Characteristic scales in Thin Shear Layers Equations (Aerodynamics)
I am struggling to understand what characteristic scales mean in the context of thin shear layer equations. I am referring mostly to the following paragraph from the book "Turbulent Shear Layers in Supersonic Flow" by Smits and Dussauge (2nd edition):

Thin shear layers are flows where the characteristic scale in the cross-stream
direction is much smaller than the characteristic scale in the streamwise direction. As a consequence, derivatives of mean quantities taken in the direction
across the flow are always much larger than similar derivatives taken in the
freestream direction. Typical examples include mixing layers, jets, wakes and
boundary layers where the pressure gradients are not too large. For this class
of flows, we can derive a set of approximate equations that are useful for the
understanding of compressible turbulent shear layers.

Does characteristic scale here refer to a some kind of order of magnitude analysis?
Thank you very much!

The scales can come from a purely mathematical origin, though not necessary for the engineering use. ...  The whole series of videos by this guy is pretty good, if you find this stuff entertaining. The boundary layer lecture builds on 4-5 concepts in nonlinear differential equations and perturbation theory, so it isn't actually a good place to start, but you can rewind to the beginning of the lecture series. He doesn't actually talk about aerodynamics at all, it's math only. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJyBkco-HSg  Also see the related (?) "multiple scale expansion" lecture

Yes, they refer to the ratio of lengths: smaller lengths in the cross stream direction.
So, for example the rate of velocity change cross stream happens over a smaller length than a comparable velocity change in the free stream direction.
